# How to revoke freeze authority and mint authority on a token

Tags: web3.js

Can you provide a simple Javascript example to revoke freeze authority and revoke mint authority on the following token :

https://solscan.io/token/6N5vU7bLqqvkoN1G4SM5pGRR4QsPpkRXQP3Nd2wg64aw?cluster=devnet

I created the token with metaplex lib, but until now I was unable to freeze authority and mint for this token.

Answer (score 5):

for mint authority just use :

```
spl-token authorize {token_address} mint --disable
```

for freeze :

```
spl-token authorize {token_address} freeze --disable
```

It's not js, it's with cli, but i guess it does the work as you want too?